# How to avoid onCropComplete useCallback function gets stuck in infinite loop when updating state of other variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, crop

I'm trying to get react-easy-crop to work. The code successfully shows a button (Upload file) which triggers a screen to select a picture. Once the picture is taken, a new modal appears and this modal shows a round cropping overlay on top of the picture. The goals is to resize the picture and save it in croppedImage so I can store it to the backend.

The issue at hand is that 'onCropComplete' is called over and over again. I can see that by putting print statements. Removing the line

`setCroppedAreaPixels(croppedAreaPixels);`

resolves the issue although it is unclear why this happens.

Can anyone help me as to why this function keeps getting called?
My code is attached below.

```js
// The `Cropper` component is on the global object as `ReactEasyCrop`. Assign to `Cropper` so we can use it like a ES6 module
window.Cropper = window.ReactEasyCrop;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } = React;

// Mock `useAxios`
function useAxios() {}

// Mock `useParams`
function useParams() {
  return {
    id: 1,
  }
}

// Mock `getCroppedImg`
function getCroppedImg() {}

const UserDetail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [res, setRes] = useState("");
  const [dateJoined, setDateJoined] = useState("");
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState("");
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  const api = useAxios();
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
  const [croppedAreaPixels, setCroppedAreaPixels] = useState(null);
  const [croppedImage, setCroppedImage] = useState(null);

  const showHideClassName = modalState
    ? "modal display-block"
    : "modal display-none";

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect!");
    const fetchData = () => {
      // make unrelated API call to backend
    };
    fetchData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [id]);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    // works - saves file to selected image and triggers cropping modal
    console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
    setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
    showModal();
  };

  const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    // function not yet called because problem in onCropComplete
    showCroppedImage();
    const sendData = () => {
      // API call to POST newly cropped image
    };
    sendData();
    hideModal();
  };

  const showModal = () => {
    setModalState(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setModalState(false);
  };

  const onCropComplete = useCallback((croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
    //problematic function, is called infinitely
    setCroppedAreaPixels(croppedAreaPixels);
    console.log(croppedAreaPixels);
  }, []);

  const showCroppedImage = useCallback(() => {
    //code not working yet, first onCropComplete should work correctly
    try {
      // Converted async/await function to promise as Stack Snippets does not support async/await when transpiling with Babel as Babel version is too old. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386097/why-wont-this-snippet-with-async-await-work-here-on-stack-overflow-snippet-edit
      const croppedImage = getCroppedImg(
        selectedImage,
        croppedAreaPixels,
        0
      ).then(() => {
        console.log("donee", { croppedImage });
        setCroppedImage(croppedImage);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, [selectedImage, croppedAreaPixels]);

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <div className="userdetail">
        <div className="profilebanner">
          <div className="profilepicture">
            <img src={avatar} alt="" className="avatar" />
            <input
              ref={inputRef}
              onChange={handleFileChange}
              type="file"
              style={{ display: "none" }}
            />
            <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}>
              Upload File
            </button>
            <div className={showHideClassName}>
              <section className="modal-main">
                <p align="center">Modal</p>
                <div className="cropper">
                  {selectedImage && (
                    <Cropper
                      image={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)}
                      crop={crop}
                      aspect={5 / 5}
                      zoom={zoom}
                      zoomSpeed={4}
                      maxZoom={3}
                      zoomWithScroll={true}
                      showGrid={true}
                      cropShape="round"
                      onCropChange={setCrop}
                      onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
                      onZoomChange={setZoom}
                    />
                  )}
                </div>
                <button onClick={handleFileUpload}>Confirm!</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={hideModal}>
                  Close
                </button>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><UserDetail /></StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin defer src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin defer src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin defer src="https://unpkg.com/tslib@1.9.1/tslib.js"></script>
<!-- tslib assigns its functions to the global object (e.g. `window.__assign`) however React Easy Crop expects it on the tslib object (e.g. `window.tslib.__assign`). This is hacky but allows React Easy Crop to find tslib functions on `window.tslib` -->
<script type="module">window.tslib = window</script>
<script crossorigin defer src="https://unpkg.com/react-easy-crop@3.3.2/umd/react-easy-crop.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Currently your code works like this:

1. On file input change, set the `selectedImage` state to the file. This causes the component to re-render.

   > ```
   > const handleFileChange = (event) => {
   >   // works - saves file to selected image and triggers cropping modal
   >   console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
   >   setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
   >   showModal();
   > };
   > ```
2. During re-render, convert the file to a blob URL and pass it in the `image` prop of the `Cropper` component.

   > ```
   > return (
   > // ...
   >   { selectedImage && (
   >     <Cropper
   >       image={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)}
   >     // ...
   >     />
   >   }
   > );
   > ```

This is a problem because the following happens during render:

1. `URL.createObjectURL` creates a new unique URL.
2. `Cropper` re-renders because of the new URL passed to `image`.
3. `onCropComplete` is called because a default crop is applied.
4. `UserDetail` component re-renders because `onCropComplete` updates state. This returns us to step 1 and causes an infinite loop.

The key thing to note is `URL.createObjectURL` is not deterministic. It produces a new result each time even with the same file, according to the algorithm in its [specification](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#url-model). See **step 9**, which generates a UUID:

> To ***generate a new blob URL***, run the following steps:
>
> 1. Let *result* be the empty string.
> 2. Append the string "`blob:`" to *result*.
> 3. Let *settings* be the [current settings object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#current-settings-object)
> 4. Let *origin* be *settings*’s [origin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-settings-object-origin).
> 5. Let *serialized* be the [ASCII serialization](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#ascii-serialisation-of-an-origin) of *origin*.
> 6. If *serialized* is "`null`", set it to an implementation-defined value.
> 7. Append *serialized* to *result*.
> 8. Append U+0024 SOLIDUS (/) to *result*.
> 9. Generate a UUID [[RFC4122](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#biblio-rfc4122)] as a string and append it to *result*.
> 10. Return *result*.

## Solution

As a result, instead of calling `URL.createObjectURL` inside the `image` prop for the `Cropper` component, call it before you set the `selectedImage` state. Demo below:

```js
// The `Cropper` component is on the global object as `ReactEasyCrop`. Assign to `Cropper` so we can use it like a ES6 module
window.Cropper = window.ReactEasyCrop;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } = React;

// Mock `useAxios`
function useAxios() {}

// Mock `useParams`
function useParams() {
  return {
    id: 1,
  }
}

// Mock `getCroppedImg`
function getCroppedImg() {}

const UserDetail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [res, setRes] = useState("");
  const [dateJoined, setDateJoined] = useState("");
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState("");
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  const api = useAxios();
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
  const [croppedAreaPixels, setCroppedAreaPixels] = useState(null);
  const [croppedImage, setCroppedImage] = useState(null);

  const showHideClassName = modalState
    ? "modal display-block"
    : "modal display-none";

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect!");
    const fetchData = () => {
      // make unrelated API call to backend
    };
    fetchData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [id]);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    // works - saves file to selected image and triggers cropping modal
    console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
    setSelectedImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
    showModal();
  };

  const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    // function not yet called because problem in onCropComplete
    showCroppedImage();
    const sendData = () => {
      // API call to POST newly cropped image
    };
    sendData();
    hideModal();
  };

  const showModal = () => {
    setModalState(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setModalState(false);
  };

  const onCropComplete = useCallback((croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
    //problematic function, is called infinitely
    setCroppedAreaPixels(croppedAreaPixels);
    console.log(croppedAreaPixels);
  }, []);

  const showCroppedImage = useCallback(() => {
    //code not working yet, first onCropComplete should work correctly
    try {
      // Converted async/await function to promise as Stack Snippets does not support async/await when transpiling with Babel as Babel version is too old. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386097/why-wont-this-snippet-with-async-await-work-here-on-stack-overflow-snippet-edit
      const croppedImage = getCroppedImg(
        selectedImage,
        croppedAreaPixels,
        0
      ).then(() => {
        console.log("donee", { croppedImage });
        setCroppedImage(croppedImage);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, [selectedImage, croppedAreaPixels]);

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <div className="userdetail">
        <div className="profilebanner">
          <div className="profilepicture">
            <img src={avatar} alt="" className="avatar" />
            <input
              ref={inputRef}
              onChange={handleFileChange}
              type="file"
              style={{ display: "none" }}
            />
            <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}>
              Upload File
            </button>
            <div className={showHideClassName}>
              <section className="modal-main">
                <p align="center">Modal</p>
                <div className="cropper">
                  {selectedImage && (
                    <Cropper
                      image={selectedImage}
                      crop={crop}
                      aspect={5 / 5}
                      zoom={zoom}
                      zoomSpeed={4}
                      maxZoom={3}
                      zoomWithScroll={true}
                      showGrid={true}
                      cropShape="round"
                      onCropChange={setCrop}
                      onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
                      onZoomChange={setZoom}
                    />
                  )}
                </div>
                <button onClick={handleFileUpload}>Confirm!</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={hideModal}>
                  Close
                </button>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><UserDetail /></StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin defer src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin defer src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin defer src="https://unpkg.com/tslib@1.9.1/tslib.js"></script>
<!-- tslib assigns its functions to the global object (e.g. `window.__assign`) however React Easy Crop expects it on the tslib object (e.g. `window.tslib.__assign`). This is hacky but allows React Easy Crop to find tslib functions on `window.tslib` -->
<script type="module">window.tslib = window</script>
<script crossorigin defer src="https://unpkg.com/react-easy-crop@3.3.2/umd/react-easy-crop.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

## Additional notes

It's also a good idea to release the object URL to aid memory management. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static#memory_management):

> #### Memory management
>
> Each time you call `createObjectURL()`, a new object URL is created, even if you've already created one for the same object. Each of these must be released by calling [`URL.revokeObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL_static) when you no longer need them.
>
> Browsers will release object URLs automatically when the document is unloaded; however, for optimal performance and memory usage, if there are safe times when you can explicitly unload them, you should do so.

I think you can do this inside the `handleFileUpload` function.